# How to retrieve the active selection when several objects are selected by the user with FabricJS v5?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

In previous versions of FabricJS, it was possible to dynamically modify the visibility of controls when the user made a multiple selection, but this is no longer possible as the **target** property no longer exists in the latest version (v5).

Here is an example of what was possible with an **older version** of FabricJS :

```
  canvas.on({
      'selection:created': (e, j) => {
        const activeSelection = e.target;
        activeSelection.setControlsVisibility({
                mb: false,
                ml: false,
                mr: false,
                mt: false,
        });
      }
  })
```

How do you retrieve the active selection object when several objects are selected on the stage?

There's a reference to this change on the FabricJS modifications page, but they don't explain how to dynamically change the controls of the current selection:
http://fabricjs.com/v5-breaking-changes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
  canvas.on({
      'selection:created': e => {
        const activeSelection = e.selected[0].group;
        activeSelection.setControlsVisibility({
                mb: false,
                ml: false,
                mr: false,
                mt: false,
        });
      }
  })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).